# Find recurrence relation of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, recurrence

Assuming n=B-A+1, I need to derive the recurrence relation of this algorithm:

```
void recurringalgorithm(int *a, int A, int B){
  if (A == B){
    for (int j=0;j<B;j++){
      cout<<a[j];  
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return;
  }
  for (int i=A;i<B;i++){
    dosomething(a[A],a[i]);
    recurringalgorithm(a,A+1,B);
    dosomething(a[A],a[i]);
  }
}
```

Help?

Comment: Is this homework or interview question? And are you sure it is `(a, A+1, B)` without involving `i`?

Comment: this is a homework problem, and yes, it is A+1, not A+i.

Comment: Looks like `n` should be `B-A+1` rather than `A-B+1` since looking at the algorithm, `A` and `B` are used as start and end respectively.

Comment: oops, you're right. my mistake. it is B-A+1. Post has been changed accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume the complexity of your recursive algorithm is `h(A,B)`.

From your code you can split `h` into 2 cases:

```
h(A,B) = { complexity-of-if-branch          if A = B
         { complexity-of-rest-of-the-code   otherwise
```

The "complexity-of-if-branch" is trivial. For "complexity-of-rest-of-the-code", since it involves `recurringalgorithm`, you'll need to include `h` again.

For instance, if the function is defined like

```
function hh(A,B) {
    for (var i = A+1; i < B; ++ i)
        hh(i, B);
}
```

Then the complexity will be

```
hh(A,B) = hh(A+1, B) + hh(A+2, B) + ... + hh(B-1, B)
```

You can compare this with your code to generalize.

(BTW, the complexity is `h(A,B) = O(B * (B-A)!)`)

Comment: thanks, so the complexity-of-if-branch is negligible in calculating the overall big-o complexity?

Comment: @zebraman: No, the "complexity-of-if-branch" is responsible of the "B" factor in `O(B * (B-A)!)`.

Comment: Whenever I see a "!" in a complexity, I cry... it's fortunate it's only homework!